# Is there any difference between "next time" and "next time around"?

Tags: difference, phrases

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *next time* and *next time around*? For example:

> If you pay for the dinner this time, **next time**/**next time around** it's on me.

Comment: No difference. The "around" is redundant.

Comment: I might use 'around' when it is a sequence of events, for example attending a course or school, or a case of history repeating itself. Not for dinner though.

Comment: "around" sounds more casual, informal

Answer (score 1):

Essentially no difference. I would say "around" is a colloquial way to add a bit of emphasis that something is repeating (or expected to repeat).